# Is Startup class run one instance per server?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

In the MVC5 template from VS 2013, there is a Startup class that is called as a result of being decorated by `OwinStartupAttribute`.

May I know whether this Startup class is run once per IIS or every time a Http request comes in?

Answer (score 0):

The class designated by this attribute is used by the OWIN framework to launch the application. See the examples in this tutorial: http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-startup-class-detection

Comment: Thanks, but it is still not clear whether "application" refers to the global application at the server level for all browsers, `or`, the application as each Http request sees it.

Comment: It refers to your application, that will be launched by the server and will serve multiple Http requests. The startup class gets called to launch the application, not per Http request.

Answer (score 0):

The class that is adorned with the `OwinStartupAttribute` is executed once per `AppDomain`.

---

OWIN middleware on the other hand is managed by Microsoft's OWIN implementation and will be executed once per request.

For example `Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware` is shown below. Under the covers the `CookieAuthenticationHandler` class is newed up by OWIN several times for each request to the server for things like images, scripts, pages and so on. You can put a break point inside the `OnValidateIdentity` to see this behavior and look at the `Context.Request.Path`.

So in short, while your "startup" class is called once per `AppDomain`, your callback delegates like `OnValidateIdentity` will fire once per http request.

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    // app.UseCookieAuthentication(...) is only called once per AppDomain
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
        Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
        {
            // callback delegate is called once per http request
            OnValidateIdentity = ctx =>
            {
                return ctx.RejectIdentity(); // Reject every identity. No one can log into my app! It's that secure.
                return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
            }
        }
    });
}
```